# jQuery Take Textarea List & Create Comma Separated Quoted List

Tags: jquery

I have a textarea that I will be inputting multiple values into and I want it to populate a text box.

Example:

Textarea:

```
123
456
789
```

Text box:

```
'123','456','789'
```

I've been trying to Google and also figure this out for a while and I cannot find anything or think of a way to get this to work.

Comment: Can you post the code you're using(HTML, JS) It helps to have a point of reference beyond what you've provided.

Comment: break on new line character and start doing it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty easy to do, just get the value of the textarea with `val` and split it by newline, then map it to surround with quotes and set the input with `val` again.

```js
$("textarea").on("input", () =>
  $("input")
  .val(
    $("textarea")
    .val()
    .split('\n')
    .map(e => `'${e}'`)));
```

```css
textarea { width:100% }
input { width:100% }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea></textarea>
<input type="text">
```

Comment: Thank you! I figured out another way right after I posted (of course): `$('#amountList').bind('input propertychange', function() {
        $('#amountOutput').val( '\'' + $('#amountList').val().replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '\',\'') + '\'');
    });`